# Why does the cloning not work as expected - Roblox lua(u)

Tags: lua, game-development, roblox, luau

I just started building a roblox game, and I need to put players in "jails" to restrict their movement.

***defaultjail is a `UnionOperation` object, its a hollow cube; like a room.***

my code (a serversided script in workspace)

```lua
local people: {{them: Model, where: Vector3, theirs: UnionOperation}} = nil; -- a table of dictionaries.
local dj: UnionOperation = game:GetService("Workspace").defaultjail; -- the default jail
local seperation = 100; -- amount of seperation on the x axis for each player

function update_people(person: Player)
    table.insert(people, {
        them = person.Character,
        where = Vector3.new(#people * seperation, 0, 0),
        theirs = dj:Clone()
    });
    local created: {them: Model, where: Vector3, theirs: UnionOperation} = people[#people];
    created.theirs.Parent = dj.Parent;
    created.theirs.Name = created.them.Name + "'s jail"
end

game:GetService("Players").PlayerAdded:Connect(function(person: Player)
    update_people(person);
    for i, v in ipairs(people) do
        local hrp: Part = v.them.HumanoidRootPart;
        v.theirs.CFrame = v.where;
        hrp.CFrame = v.where;
    end
end)
```

**expected behavior step-by-step:**
a player joins the workspace.defaultjail object is cloned. it gets moved to the workspace and its named "x's jail" the jail gets moved to p*100, 0, 0 (p being how many players are registered into the script) the player gets teleported to the center of the jail

**the actual behavior:**
everything goes as expected at first glance. then you realize the default jail hasnt been cloned and the user was just teleported inside the defaultjail object

**what ive tried**
ive tried messing around with how i clone the default jail.
ive tried messing around with the way everything is moved around (the actual parts and stuff in the game)

Comment: Rather than initializing `people` as `nil`, have you tried initiating it as an empty table? `people = {}`. I'm thinking that since `people` is never initialized, `#people` is always zero, regardless of the `table.insert` calls